# [Flask]-Customising Flask-user login

Tags: flask, flask-login

Have been working on Flask-user for the user management system, But I couldn't see a way to customise the login page and registration page. I installed flask-user using pip

```
pip install flask-user
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `templates` folder, create a new folder named `flask_user` and you can copy the `login.html` and `register.html` pages used by `flask-user` to the newly created folder. Then you can modify them as per your requirements. These files will override the pages used by `flask-user`.

Answer (score 0):

## From official flask-user documentation

You can get a boilerplate (an app example) at https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User-starter-app

## Other resources to learn

### 1. Flask-mega tutorial

Here are a few resources online that can really help you customizing your user-login and also other topics:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins

This tutorial uses openid but explains everything with code examples i.e.

app/views.py

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, session, url_for, request, g
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, login_required
from app import app, db, lm, oid
from .forms import LoginForm
from .models import User

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@oid.loginhandler
def login():
    if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['remember_me'] = form.remember_me.data
        return oid.try_login(form.openid.data, ask_for=['nickname', 'email'])
    return render_template('login.html', 
                           title='Sign In',
                           form=form,
                           providers=app.config['OPENID_PROVIDERS'])
```

### 2. Exploreflask.com

Complete free step by step guide. Also comes with a full chapter for your problem in the 'users' chapter.

Answer (score 0):

[Follow the official link](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_app.html)

Default flask-user BasicApp has email based authorization.

- We can change into user based authorization
- Change the model

  ```
  class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
     __tablename__ = 'users'
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     active = db.Column('is_active', db.Boolean(), nullable=False, server_default='1')
     username = db.Column(db.String(100, collation='NOCASE'), nullable=False, unique=True)
     password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, server_default='')        
     first_name = db.Column(db.String(100, collation='NOCASE'), nullable=False, server_default='')
     last_name = db.Column(db.String(100, collation='NOCASE'), nullable=False, server_default='')
     # Define the relationship to Role via UserRoles
     roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary='user_roles')
  ```
- In config change the following lines:

  `USER_ENABLE_EMAIL = False  # Enable email authentication
  USER_ENABLE_USERNAME = True  # Disable username authentication`

> Insert the Default two users by Username. Replace Existing code by following code.

```
    if not User.query.filter(User.username == 'member').first():
    user = User(
        username='member',
        password=user_manager.hash_password('Password1'),
    )
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()

# Create 'admin@example.com' user with 'Admin' and 'Agent' roles
if not User.query.filter(User.username == 'admin').first():
    user = User(
        username='admin',
        password=user_manager.hash_password('Password1'),
    )
    user.roles.append(Role(name='Admin'))
    user.roles.append(Role(name='Agent'))
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
```