# Overriding Flask-User/Flask-Login's default templates

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-user

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201102/flask-customising-flask-user-login), but the answer does not seem to work for me.

I use Flask User (which extends Flask Login, I believe) and for the most part it works very well. I have built my own completely fresh templates for sign in and registration, rather than using their provided ones. Following the [documentation](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring_settings.html), I have placed these templates at `templates/flask_user/login.html`, `templates/flask_user/register.html` and so on.

I have also set `USER_UNAUTHENTICATED_ENDPOINT = "login"` and `USER_UNAUTHORIZED_ENDPOINT = "login"` in my config file, where `login` is the name of my login route.

The problem is that if I'm signed out and I try to directly access a page that requires the user to be logged in, I will be sent to `http://localhost:5000/user/sign-in` and shown the `Flask-Login` sign in page. Two things wrong with this: 1) This is not the correct route for signing in, and 2) This is not the correct template for signing in.

I'd be grateful for any help anybody can suggest for this, please.

**EDIT:**

Code from `__init__.py` that initialises the app and the LoginManager:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.context_processor
def inject_production_status():
    return dict(production=True)

# Initialise flask_login
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'
login.refresh_view = "login"
login.needs_refresh_message = "Please sign in again to access this page"
```

UserManager is defined at the bottom of `models.py`:

```
user_manager = UserManager(app, db, User)
```

Comment: Could you please edit the question to add the `create_app` function (or the code where the Flask `app` is created and modified with `UserManager` ) ?

Comment: @JBLaf Is that what you need? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented @JBLaf's suggestion, but this did not resolve the problem. I realised that the default sign in page I was being presented was not actually `flask-login`'s `login.html` template, but its `login_auth0.html` template. This was a template that I hadn't replaced in my own `flask_user` folder, as I didn't think it necessary.

Two ways to resolve this:

1. Set `USER_ENABLE_AUTH0 = False`. This makes it use the `login.html` template, which is my own custom one. However, this caused problems for me down the line because I do allow SSO sign-ins. So the better solution was:
2. Create a `login-auth0.html` file in my `templates/flask_user` folder, containing only the line `{% include 'flask_user/login.html' %}`.

Now Flask-User will try to redirect to the auth0 template, which will instead render my `login.html` template.

Answer (score 1):

`UserManager` needs to be initialized in `__init__.py` and not in `models.py`. `UserManager` will take care of the initialization of `LoginManager`.

You need to replace in `__init__.py` :

```
# Initialize flask_login
login = UserManager (app, db, User)
login.login_view = 'login'
login.refresh_view = "login"
login.needs_refresh_message = "Please sign in again to access this page"
```

by

```
# Initialize flask_user
from .models.user_models import User
user_manager = UserManager (app, db, User)
...
# login is now accessible by user_manager.login_manager
```

(And remove it from `models.py`)

Here is an example: 
[https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User-starter-app/blob/master/app/**init**.py](https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User-starter-app/blob/master/app/__init__.py)

Irrelevant to the question but just in case: In the long term it will be easier for you to have a look at `app.config.from_object` to handle more easily production and development configurations.

Comment: Thank you. I implemented your suggestions but continued to have the same issue. I have now fixed it I think, but what I did is too long to fit in this comment, so will post another answer below.